# How to save all parameters of a function as a string?

Tags: python

I am looking to save the input parameters of a function as a string. I am using Python 3.7. I want so save that string for debugging.

What I could do easily would be something like this:

```
def Model(par1=150, par2=100)

#some processing

return results, par1

parameters = str(par1) + str(par2)
```

However, I want to be able to automatically save all parameters, even if I add more parameters later. So if I add a par3 = 300 to the function, "parameters" would also contain str(par3), instead of me having to add it manually.

The behavior I would like to have is something like this:

```
def Model(--any number of parameters--)

#some processing

return results

parameters = --all parameters of Model--
```

The reason I would like to have it done automatically is that I expect that otherwise it would cause more trouble than it being worse, as I would have to remember to manually change this all the time.

Is it possible to save ALL parameters of a function as a string (or in any other way that lets me easily check later which parameters a function ran with)?

Comment: thanks! Those links were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
def foo(param1, param2):
    parameters = list(locals().items())
    print(parameters)
foo(100,200)

# Outputs 
[('param1', 100), ('param2', 200)]
```

Comment: thanks! locals() was exactly what I needed. I simply save it as

```
args = locals()
```

at the beginning of the function

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer if it was useful

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with

```
args = locals()
```

at the beginning of the function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a bit fancy, you could create a decorator and use it wherever you need it. Here is just a simple one I wrote:

```py
from functools import wraps

def save_params(func):
  @wraps(func)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    print ('Calling {}({}{}{})'.format(
      func.__name__,
      ', '.join(map(str, args)),
      ', ' if kwargs else '',
      ', '.join('{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items())
    ))
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper

@save_params
def f(a, b, c=3):
  return a + b + c
```

Now whenever you call `f()` the arguments will get printed. `@save_params` could be used for any other methods to keep track of params passed in during debugging. It looks like this:

```py
>>> f(1, 2)
Calling f(1, 2)
6
>>> f(1, 2, c=7)
Calling f(1, 2, c=7)
10
```